# How to best split long strings?

Tags: paragraphs, xstring

I would like to do a simple `\StrSplit` (from the xstring package) on a string I have, however, the string in question may contain a `\par`, and it appears that `\@xs@StrSpl@t@@`, which I can only imagine is an internal xstring macro, is not a long macro, so it causes an error.

Are there any workarounds? Other packages with similar functionality that accept long strings? A way to remove `\par` temporarily and put it back later?

EDIT: I only actually need to split off the first character, so if there's a way to do that directly on arbitrary strings (with the semantics of `\noexpand`), that would work too.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this to get the first character:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\long\def\test#1{%
  \long\def\getfirstchar##1##2;{%
  \def\storeone{##1}
}
 \getfirstchar#1;
}
\makeatother


\test{This is \par something}

\storeone
\end{document}
```

The macro gets the first letter and stores it in another macro called `storeone.` I am not  sure what you want to do exactly, other than get the first letter, perhaps you can expand on your question a bit. You can also have a look at `source2e`, there are similar commands such as `\@firstoftwo`.

Comment: Why the `makeatletter` there? You don't seem to use `@`.

Comment: @centrifugal force:) You right they are not needed, I just typed them planning to use @ and then thought I maybe obscuring the concepts.

Comment: Also, this solution doesn't work if the string contains a semicolon; I need it to work for (nearly) arbitrary text. I was thinking maybe something clever with `\futurelet` to remove a token from the stream and then put it back. EDIT: picked a dummy command as a delimiter. Still doesn't handle curly-brace constructs well. I'm thinking maybe there's a futurelet trick?

Comment: @copro The delimiting is not a big issue, you can delimit it with anything else you want (say `@end`). However, if you want to catch any type of character is another issue. Then `futurelet` is the answer. See how `\@ifnextchar` works, you need to clarify your case a bit better.